# Dual Boot Goes to Win8 Doesn't even Show Grub screen

Tags: grub2

This is NOT an installation problem question. I've had both op sys working fine side-by-side for a couple of weeks now. I'm using Ubunutu 12.04 64-bit.

This morning when I tried to switch from Win8 to Ubuntu, it just rebooted into Win8. No grub screen whatsoever. This is the 3rd machine I've had dual-booting & have never seen this, but then Win8 is a 1st for me & has thrown some pretty awesome blocks in the path to get to here. Atrocious op sys...

I'm assuming the ASUS updater did this yesterday. (ASUS R503U)

So, do I just put the Ubuntu disk in & reinstall grub?

Comment: It's working! Thanks Janman & Saurav Kumar.

Here's how I got into Ubuntu:
1) mouse over upper or lower right corner of screen to open the "Charms Bar"
2) click "Settings" icon. Looks like a gear, mines towards the bottom of the charms bar
3) click "Change PC Settings"
4) click "General" in the left pane
5) scroll to the bottom in the right pane, under "Advanced Startup", click "Restart Now" button
6) click "Use a Device"
7) click "Ubuntu"

FINALLY! Grub appears.

From here I followed the instructions Saurav gave. Click "OK" in EFI Detected alert box & ignore. Instructions were easy to follow.

Comment: Could you write that comment as a answer. Comments can be removed for whatever motive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No you need not to install Ubuntu again**

**Here is your solution:**

I prefer you to use Ubuntu Grub Menu, that is let Ubuntu to allow you to chose which OS you want to boot (Windows or Ubuntu).

Here are the steps that would help you..

Boot from your Ubuntu LiveCD/DVD or Ubuntu bootable USB and select 'Try Ubuntu' (not 'Install Ubuntu'). When Ubuntu starts open terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following commands:

Installing boot-repair ( a good s/w to fix grub ):

```
    $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
    $ sudo apt-get update
    $ sudo apt-get install boot-repair
    Run boot-repair from your system or type: (boot-repair &) in terminal
```

When started select Option 'Recommended Repair' from out of two options:

'Recommended Repair' & 'Advanced Options'.

Follow very easy onscreen instruction, it will build/fix your grub menu..

Restarting your system may list all the Operating Systems installed in your HDD.
Be sure that you have properly shut down Windows 8, before starting these steps..

You can get more help on - [Using Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: I had no need to use the live CD/DVD after I found out how to find the Win8 boot loader. But the rest of it was so very helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: Sounds great! At last everything works!! Cheers Up.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can boot to Ubuntu too from the Windows Boot Loader, but you have to turn Secure Boot off (And maybe some other features too, depends on your system).

However I would strongly suggest that you install Grub from Ubuntu using [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), which is a very neat program for repairing Boot Loaders, among a lot of other features too.

Comment: Took a lot of research to figure out how to find Win8 boot loader. nothing in this opsys is intuitive. See comment above to find out how hidden it is -- 7 levels deep!